# How to change backcolor of alert box in sencha?

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, sencha-architect

I got an issue with the alert box of sencha touch control.
Issue is: I would like to change background color of alert box, I tried to implement CSS but its not letting me to do it.

Is there any other way to change background color of alert box in sencha?

Early reply will be appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: Got solution:http://www.mindstick.com/Forum/945/How%20to%20chnage%20backcolor%20of%20alert%20box%20in%20sencha%203f#6753005040614

Answer (score 0):

Use below css classes to change MessageBox bg color and MessageBox text properties.

```
// To change messagebox background color

.x-msgbox
 {
    background-color: #fff;

 }

// To change messagebox text properties
 .x-msgbox-dark .x-msgbox-text {
    color: #000 !important;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

// To change messagebox title
.x-toolbar-dark .x-title {
    color:#000 !important;
    font-size: 20px !important;
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}
```

Hope it helps.

Thanks Gendaful